# How can I solve a PDE on the real line with DSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I would like to know if it is possible to solve a PDE on the real line by using DSolve.
For exapmle cosider the heat equation  $u_t=u_{xx}$, $u(x,0)=e^{-x^2}$
for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

the code I tried is

```
f[x_] := e^(-x^2)

DSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], 
  u[x, 0] == f[x]}, u, {Element[x, Reals], t}]
```

but that doesn't work, how could I do this?

Comment: For me works fine, because I have read the help pages.Try: `f[x_] := Exp[-x^2]; DSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], 
  u[x, 0] == f[x]}, u[x, t], {x, t}]`

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk you cheated by reading the help pages :)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
f[x_] := Exp[-x^2]
DSolve[{D[u[x, t], {t, 1}] == D[u[x, t], {x, 2}], 
  u[x, 0] == f[x]}, u, {x, t}]
```

Comment: @Mariusz Iwaniuk Beat me to it.